# Finite commutative group schemes whose exponent coincides with its rank

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

In group theory, a finite commutative group $G$ contains an element whose order is the exponent of $G$. Thus, If the exponent of $G$ is the same as the order of $G$, it must be that $G$ is cyclic. Conversely, in a finite cyclic group, the exponent is the same as the order. Thus, we have a nice characterization of finite commutative groups with the exponent coinciding with the order (namely cyclic groups).

I was wondering if there are analogous known characterizations of finite commutative group schemes whose exponent (that is, the smallest number natural number $n$, such that the morphism $[n]:G\rightarrow G$ is the zero morphism) coincides with its rank. Or if there are partial answers in either direction (i.e. sufficient or necessary conditions for exponent coinciding with rank).

For me, even answers in special cases would be very helpful, for example, for group schemes over a field (where you can feel free to add more restrictions on the field)

Comment: I haven't thought much about the relevance of what I'm writing, but there is a notion of a finite flat group scheme being *cyclic* in Katz and Mazur's book Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, chapter 1.